# How to install protobuf on windows? (Win7x64/MinGW)

Tags: c++, mingw, protocol-buffers, autotools

C++-Protobuf does not compile in VS2012. Now I want to use MinGW to compile it on windows. Can someone please give me some brief headwords on how to compile protobuf on Win7 x64. I already installed MinGW with the GUI installer. Google writes as MinGW setup notice that I should refer to the Unix installation notes. But I cant figure out how to use the auto tools on windows.

**Edit**

Okay this is what I've done until now:

```
$ mount C:/ WinDir
$ cd ./[...]/protobuf.2.4.1
$ ./configure
$ minGW32-make.exe
$ minGW32-make.exe check
```

minGW32-make.exe runs without errors, but no tests are running and I cant find libprotobuf.lib. There are some libprotobuf.dll but I need the lib, dont I?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an MSys console together with your MinGW instalation. This console provides an linux-like environment in which you should be able to use autotools normally.

If MSys is not installed, you can grab it from the MinGW site too.

`cd` to your directory with sources and try the usual:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Some libraries cause problems on Windows but most compile well with MinGW and MSys. Come back and add more info to your question if you run into specific problems.

---

Edit:

> minGW32-make.exe runs without errors, but no tests are running and I cant find libprotobuf.lib. There are some libprotobuf.dll but I need the lib, dont I?.

Usually for a dynamic library you'd get `protobuf.dll` (the dynamic library) and `libprotobuf.a` (the static wrapper library).

When linking, just pass `-lprotobuf` to the linker - it will look for both `libprotobuf.a` and `protobuf.lib`.

(`.lib` is another static library format, which is partially handled by MinGW but not native here.)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP did?

Comment: Might have been the case, *which I couldn't know before he edited the post*.

Comment: Whoops, the OP had that edited in after you posted. Sorry about that! Apparently the vote has been locked, so if you make a minor change to it I will of course revise my downvote!

Answer (score 1):

You will not work with a `.lib` file when using the MinGW toolchain. Instead, you are able to link against the dll directly. [The MinGW Wiki explains this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL).

Comment: +1 for a good reference. But I assume that "linking with the DLL directly" will link it in statically instead of dynamically, is that correct? IIRC for dynamic linking you either load the library [manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) or use a static wrapper that does that for you - that's what the `libNAME.a` wrappers generated together with the DLL do under the hood.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can have the loader code generated automatically by just passing the DLL to the linker with some flag; can you confirm?

Comment: That depends on how he links exactly. I do it as mentioned in the Wiki by calling `g++ -o example_exe.exe example_exe.o example_dll.dll` which does not require the any input library.

Comment: Yup, it appears to work. Thanks for pointing this out. I wonder what DLLs are supported in this way (like, can they be C dlls from MSVC too?).

Comment: No, this will only work with DLLs created by the MinGW toolchain. Its sort of the "normal" way to link against libraries (.so in that case) on *NIX systems and MinGW mirrors this on windows.

Answer (score -1):

I could get dll and lib both. This is when you do not want static lib file and want to use dll and lib file. 
You need to make following changes in Protobuf code:

1. Open the project in VS. Or any other editor. I use VS2015.
2. In libProtoBuf project settings, in C/C++ Preprocessor add following flags.
   PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS; LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS;
   Those flags will export information from profobuf using dllexport
3. in ur client code where you are using Protobuf, define: PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS. Which will make protobuf includes to use dllimport.

Once you do step 2, you will see both dll and lib in your output folder. Otherwise, you will always see just dll and not lib file.

Hope this helps. If not, please write a message here and I can help you getting this sorted out.