# How to parse protobuf packets in Wireshark

Tags: python, lua, wireshark, lua-table, tshark

My goal is to have a plugin/dissector that can parse a protocol based on protobuf (UDP).
I found on the web an Auto-generate Wireshark/Ethereal dissector plugins for Protocol Buffer messages: https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-wireshark/
when i follow the [ReadMe](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/protobuf-wireshark/README-runtime-v0.1.txt) file i skipped "STEP 1: Install Wireshark from source" since i have it installed (version 1.12.3).

**Step 2: Prepare Protocol Buffers** -

> this step i dont understend, how do i install **libprotobuf** and
>   where?

**Step 3: Updating wireshark configuration file** -

> I'm not sure what is "wireshark_src_dir"

I created a wireshark.conf file with:
*wireshark_src_dir*     : C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark
*wireshark_install_dir* : C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark
*wireshark_version*     : 1.12.3

**Step 4: Run make_wireshark_plugin.py** - for that step i downloaded and installed python-3.6.0-amd64.exe.

> When i run this i get an error that:   Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\ProtoBuff\protobuff\make_wireshark_plugin.py", line
>   91, in 
>       f=open("configure.in","r") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'configure.in'.
>
> This file realy doesn't exists in the package i downloaded from
>   github. Where do i get this file? do i need to create such?   What is
>   this make_wireshark_plugin.py generates?

**Step 5: Create proto configuration files** - All proto configuration files need to be in /usr/share/wireshark/protobuf or
$HOME/.wireshark/protobuf.

> i dont have a share folder and protobuf folder in wireshark
>   installation path.   Can i simply put the proto configuration files in
>   the plugins folder?

Comment: Probably, `libprotobuf` is a package: `$ apt list libprotobuf*`

Comment: Assuming that libprotobuf is a package.   where do i get it? how do i install it?

Comment: yes i am a windows user

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616477/how-to-install-protobuf-on-windows-win7x64-mingw)

Answer (score 8):

New features about Protobuf and gRPC dissectors have been added into Wireshark since version 3.2.0:

- Protobuf files (*.proto) can now be configured to enable more precise parsing of serialized Protobuf data (such as gRPC).
- The message of stream gRPC method can now be parsed with supporting of HTTP2 streaming mode reassembly feature.
- User can specify protobuf search paths (where has *.proto files), and the UDP ports to protobuf message type maps at the Protobuf protocol preferences.
- If your own dissectors need invoke protobuf dissector, you can pass the message type to Protobuf dissector by data parameter (in C) or pinfo->private_table["pb_msg_type"] (pinfo.private["pb_msg_type"] in lua).

Another two new features will be released in 3.3.0 or 3.4.0:

- Protobuf fields can be dissected as wireshark (header) fields that allows user input the full names of Protobuf fields or messages in Filter toolbar for searching.
- Dissector based on Protobuf can register itself to a new 'protobuf_field' dissector table, which is keyed with the full names of fields, for further parsing fields of BYETS or STRING type.

References:

- https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/wireshark-3.2.0.html
- https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChProtobufSearchPaths.html
- https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChProtobufUDPMessageTypes.html

Answer (score 4):

You could use this one instead, which does not require compiling anything: https://github.com/128technology/protobuf_dissector

Comment: my protocol structure is: (1) 4 bytes (2) 4 bytes (3) the protobuf. how can i make the plugin you provide to work with my structre?  can i pill the 8 bytes first and then use the plugin? (i dont care about the 8 bytes, it's legacy...)

Comment: please refer to last comment @hadriel

Comment: Yes you should be able to just skip the first 8 bytes - the protobuf dissector assumes the `TVB` given to it (from the beginning) is a protobuf message, so as long as you skip those 8 bytes you should be good.

Comment: Consider the current limitations: option "message_set_wire_format=true" not supported, options "packed=true" not supported, 'import' statement 'weak' mode not supported, etc.

Comment: You should never use "message_set_wire_format=true", as that was for an old internal google format.

"import weak" is debatable, since the whole point of using the files for wireshark is to decode them, so missing files is pointless.

"packed=true" is definitely a missing option that should be implemented in the dissector. I just didn't use it at the time.